# Настройка сети на ASPLinux 11.2 через мобильный телефон

Tags: windows, linux

Как настроить интернет на ASPLinux 11.2 через мобильный телефон Nokia N 73 через шнур USB?

Настроил модем, работает нормально, но не идет передача данных. Пытаюсь зайти на www.google.ru не заходит. Ничего не выдает, стоит на месте и все, передача данных не идет, хотя с модемом все в порядке. Подскажите, может надо в какой-то программе галочку поставить. Windows у меня лицензионная, в синей коробке, с 5 cd и dwd, даже исходные тексты есть. Вот только проблема с интернетом ...

Answer (score 1):

c ASPLinux сильно не знаком. Для начала узнай, видит ли система телефон и кабель (кабеля часто идут со своим контроллером). в этом по юсб поможет lsusb. Если есть контроллер кабеля - хорошо, идем дальше. щупаем виртуальный com-порт и опрашиваем модем. в этом поможет wvdial, а точнее `wvdialconf имя_файла` опросит com на предмет наличия модема и его работоспособности. ставится apt-get install wvdial или yum install wvdial в зависимости от дистра..

Answer (score 0):

У меня бил такой опит, только я подключался через блютус!! Поставил блютус, нашол телефон, добавил устройство и все класно потом просто на устройтсве нажимаеш правой кнопкой миши и вибираем dial-up!!